# "View (null)'s profile" when tapping on ⋮ on answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

On the iOS app, go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/652760/1402846), then tap on the **⋮** button (on the bottom right of the answer, above the comments).
It shows an [action sheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW36), with one of the options being:

> View (null)'s profile

[image: Screenshot - Action Sheet]

Tapping on this option shows an error message: "Could not find user."

---

Also, the profile picture of the answer is wrong. It does not match that of any of the users in [the entire revision history of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/652760/revisions).

[image: Screenshot]

In fact, the picture in the screenshot comes from [another answer on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883417/1402846).

---

Version: Stack Exchange iOS App Version 1.0.1.86, 1.0.1.87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were missing some community wiki handling in this usecase.

This will be fixed in the next beta release, version 1.0.1.88.

Comment: Verified fixed in v1.0.1.88.